# 2-factor authentication with twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm using twilio to send 2 factor authentication messages. I am trying in trial version, before sending message to a phone number I have to configure that number on twilio first. Is it necessary in the paid version? Thank you

Comment: Does the pricing page of Authy by Twilio help you ? 
https://www.twilio.com/authy/pricing

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you upgrade your account you will be able to send messages to any number without verifying that number with Twilio first. That is just a [trial account restriction](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations).